# Refresh ag-grid on Observable subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, ag-grid

**I am struggling to refresh ag-grid on subscription of an observable.**

I have following piece of code which works well.

```
     this.marketConfigs = this._regionProductConfigService.getMarketConfig();              
           this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.createColumnDefs();
            this.gridOptions.rowData = this.marketConfigs;
```

But since I am trying to put a drop-down in columns of ag-grid, I wanted the column config to be created once we receive data. So I changed the code to following :

```
this._refDataService.getAllCurrencies().subscribe(
            (data: ICurrency[]) => {
                this.financingCurrencies = data;               
                this.marketConfigs = this._regionProductConfigService.getMarketConfig();              
                this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.createColumnDefs();
               this.gridOptions.rowData = this.marketConfigs;                
                this.gridOptions.enableColResize = true;
                this.gridOptions.api.refreshView();
            },
            err => console.log(err)
        );
```

But it doesnt show any thing in grid. Can someone help?

Comment: can you check if is there a draw() method? so somehting like  this.gridOptions.draw()

Comment: No, there is no draw() method. Ideally this.gridOptions.api.refreshView() should force grid to redraw itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gridOptions.colDefs and gridOptions.rowData are "read once" properties - they're read on Grid initialization and not looked at again.

To do dynamic post-init setting of row or columns, you need to use the API.

Change

```
this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.createColumnDefs(); 
this.gridOptions.rowData = this.marketConfigs;
```

To this:

```
this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.createColumnDefs()); 
this.gridOptions.setRowData(this.marketConfigs);
```

And it should work as expected. Note if you use the API as per the above you won't need to call refreshView - the methods above will do it for you.

Comment: what if the grid's rowData is bound to an observable? and that changes overtime?

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan a bit late now, but you can bind your row data as normal, and in the template declare it as follows: `[rowData]="rowData | async"`