# ag-grid does not refresh when using Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, angular2-observables

I'm trying to bind the Angular-2 ag-grid with an Observable. The data in the grid is shown as expected when the grid loads for the first time. Following is the code that does this:

```
  this.settingsService.gen.subscribe(
  (settings) => {
    this.gridOptions.rowData = settings;
  });
```

I have set the grid options in the constructor of the typescript class in the component.

Now, when I update the data for the observable, I see the updated changes propagated to the 'settings' (shown above), but the grid does not refresh with the new data.

I have tried all possible ways to refresh the grid using gridOptions.api.refreshView(). I also tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271497/refresh-ag-grid-on-observable-subscribe). Unfortunately, none of them worked.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried `api.setDatasource(datasource)` or `api.setRowData(rows)` instead of updating rowData ?

Comment: I tried that options as well. Refreshing the grid view in setTimeout callback did the trick actually.

 this.settingsService.gen.subscribe(
  (settings) => {
    this.gridOptions.rowData = settings;

          setTimeout(() => {
            this.gridOptions.api.refreshView();
          }, 0);
  });

Comment: in my template i gave `<ag-grid-angular #agGrid
                                 style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"
                                 class="ag-theme-bootstrap"
                                 [rowData]="transactions | async"`
and rowData gets updated whenever transactions is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I set the gridOptions `deltaRowDataMode: true`, and `getRowNodeId: data => data.id` check https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#method-3-delta-row-data for more info